# Pipeline included in cross validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am using Python 2.7 and Scikit.

I am wondering if is wise to use pipeline when doing cross validation.

Consider following example:

```
#Pipeline
pipe_rf = Pipeline([('pca', PCA(n_components=80)),
                    ('clf',RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100))])
pipe_rf.fit(X_train_s,y_train_s)

pred = pipe_rf.predict(X_test)

#CrossValidation
from sklearn import cross_validation
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(pipe_rf, 
                                          X_train,
                                          y_train, 
                                          cv=10,
                                          scoring='f1')
print 'Train score is: %.5f' % scores.mean()
```

Like this the CV module will apply the PCA step 10 times, which is very consuming and unnecessary. And I didn't include any other steps.

Comment: Modelling-wise, what you are doing is the correct thing. Of course it applies PCA 10 times but this is the proper thing to do. You could first run the PCA on the whole dataset and then CV only the Random Forest, but this would be semi-supervised learning and would be applicable only to specific cases (e.g. Kaggle competitions).

Comment: Please can you be more specific? Why and how is applying PCA 10x in CV different from applying PCA before. FYI this is real-case, not kaggle.

Comment: Well, why don't you fit the RF on the whole dataset and then use it to predict on X_test (part of the whole dataset)? It's because you are gaining information about the test data during training. Exactly the same applies to PCA. As an experiment, please apply the PCA on the whole dataset and then separately to each CV split and compare the eigenvectors. They will NOT be exactly the same as the ones fitted on the whole dataset. This shows that fitting PCA on the whole dataset means gaining insight about the distribution of the test data during training; this won't be available in a real setting